# Slider Widget moveTo, changed into value but gives NaN

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I got the following problem

My sliders works not nice anymore and gives errors. This because of updates from jquery and other things.

I got the slider on my website (sorry no images yet). It got the slider and the next prev buttons.
When I click on the slider or the buttons a nice slide comes in front.

This will be done with the following code in the old way:

```
initPL_slider = function() {
    var steps = Math.ceil(parseInt(pl.total)/parseInt(view[pl.view][0]))-1;
    var contentwidth = (parseInt($("#pl_content").innerWidth())+100);

$("#pl_slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: (steps*parseInt(view[pl.view][0])),
        handle: ".pl_handle",
        step: parseInt(view[pl.view][0]),
        change: function(event, ui){
            var dir = "";

            if(ui.value > pl.limitstart) dir = "-";
            pl.limitstart = ui.value;
            $("#pl_content").animate({ 
                left: dir+contentwidth+"px",
                opacity: 0
              }, 250, 'linear', function(){
                  $("#pl_content").css({left:"0px", opacity:1});
                  retrieveContent(false);
              }
            );
        }
    });

    if(steps < 1){
        $("#pl_slider").slider("option", "disabled", true );
    }    
}

setPLmenuData = function(){
    var steps = Math.ceil(parseInt(pl.total)/parseInt(view[pl.view][0]))-1;


    $("#pl_prev").click(function(){
        if(pl.limitstart > 0){
            $("#pl_slider").slider("moveTo", "-="+view[pl.view][0]);
        }
    });


    $("#pl_next").click(function(){

        if(steps > 0){              
            if(pl.limitstart < (parseInt(view[pl.view][0])*steps)){
                $("#pl_slider").slider("moveTo", "+="+view[pl.view][0]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Using:

jQuery 1.2.6 - New Wave Javascript

and

jQuery UI Slider
 Copyright 2008 Paul Bakaus

But now I get more and more  Error loading XML data errors and looking for a solution. So I first update Jquery and Jquery ui
Version:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The Error loading XML data errors are gone and the slider works fine. The problem is the next and prev button. When I click, I got a NaN error. It seems the calculation of the Limitstart is missing. I change moveTo into value, because moveTo is deprecated.

the link ....&limitstart=NaN&limit=25 and some new code (value)

```
    $("#pl_prev").click(function(){
        if(pl.limitstart > 0){
            $("#pl_slider").slider("value", "-="+view[pl.view][0]);
        }
    });

    $("#pl_next").click(function(){

        if(steps > 0){              
            if(pl.limitstart < (parseInt(view[pl.view][0])*steps)){
                $("#pl_slider").slider("value", "+="+view[pl.view][0]);
            }
        }
    });
```

I am lost. How do I get the right limitstart calculation in the link?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing the following code.

```
$("#pl_prev").click(function(){
        if(pl.limitstart > 0){
            $("#pl_slider").slider("value", "-="+view[pl.view][0]);
        }
    });

    $("#pl_next").click(function(){

        if(steps > 0){              
            if(pl.limitstart < (parseInt(view[pl.view][0])*steps)){
                $("#pl_slider").slider("value", "+="+view[pl.view][0]);
            }
        }
    });
```

into

```
$("#pl_prev").click(function(){

    if(pl.limitstart > 0){
        var curr = $("#pl_slider").slider("value");
        var thisHandle = view[pl.view][0];
        $("#pl_slider").slider( "value", curr - thisHandle);
    }
});

$("#pl_next").click(function(){
if(steps > 0){  
        if(pl.limitstart < (parseInt(view[pl.view][0])*steps)){

        var curr = $("#pl_slider").slider("value");
        var thisHandle2 = view[pl.view][0];
        $("#pl_slider").slider("value", curr + thisHandle2);
        }
    }
});
```

Slider value code was not complete. Since jQuery UI 1.7 
startValue and moveTo removed in favor of value and values options and methods.